# Is there a callback for ViewCell fully laid out in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, listview, autolayout

I have a UITableView with cells, the relevant part of the layout looks like this:

[image: Layout]

everything is fine until i try to add shadows to that button(orange) and view ($-), this happens:

[image]

The problem is that the view is not fully set in awakeFromNib, and it also not fully set during

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

So when can i add the shadow to those views without having to worry about the size not being set correctly yet?

Aditional Info: if i set it during the cell setup, it does not work at first, but after scrolling it gets fixed for as long as the view is open.

Edit 1: how do i add the shadows? I call a func for the cell that calls the next method passing the view as parameter, i think that @DonMag suggestion should work, subclassing should work, but is there no way to know when all the view is laid out in a TableView?

```
static func addShadowToView(view: UIView, CornerRadius: CGFloat){

    view.layer.cornerRadius = CornerRadius
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds,
                                  cornerRadius: view.layer.cornerRadius)
    view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you are "adding shadows." The best option is to subclass your views and have them add their own shadows.

Comment: @DonMag i edited the question to add the way i "add the shadow" and i do think subclassing might be the best option, but the question remains, is there any way of knowing when the view is fully set? (no more changes in sizes for its subviews)

Comment: OK - well, you don't indicate *when* you are calling `addShadowToView` ... but, you can override `layoutSubviews()` in your cell class and you may be successful setting the `shadowPath` at that point.

Comment: @DonMag i am sorry if i was not clear but i do state in the question that i tried adding the shadow in 2 places both in the awakeFromNib and in the cell setup from the tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath).
i will try that thanks!! Edit: LayoutSubviews() does not work :C, the result is the same as calling it from the tableView, its wrong when you enter the view and get fixed after scrolling

Comment: yeah, overriding `layoutSubviews()` was just something to try. Again, best bet is to subclass your views and setup the shadows in *their* `layoutSubviews()` func.

Comment: yah subclassing works, i still wonder if there is anything that let me do it without subclassing tho, thanks for the help.